# Вывод данных из MySQ. Категории

Tags: php, mysql

Нуждаюсь в помощи. Не могу найти информации.
Есть таблица shop_category строка server - имеет ид серверов(в которых надо выводить категорию).
Вывожу категорию таким кодом

```
$category_items = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM shop_category WHERE server ='".htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['idserver']))."' ORDER BY id ASC ");
```

в server стоит 1,2 -ид серверов. Как сделать что бы работал вывод(сейчас не выводит если указать 1,2 и так далее - только одиночные числа)

Answer (score 0):

Использовать перечисление айдишников, через IN

```
$category_items = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM shop_category WHERE server IN(3,16) ORDER BY id ASC ")
```

Comment: Пример можете скинуть?где использовать?  server ='".htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['idserver']))."'

Comment: $category_items = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM shop_category WHERE server IN(".htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['idserver'])).") ORDER BY id ASC ");    так?

Comment: выводит только на первом сервере(1) хотя стоит 1,2

Comment: Вам mysqli->query выведет конечно 1 резульатт, нужно все после запроса взять в fetch_array или fetch_object

Comment: Точнее, query ее выведет результат, а отдаст объект, а этот объект уже перегонять в fetch

Comment: можешь помочь? ?

Comment: Возьми в базу напрямую дай такой запрос, через навикат, пхпадин или что ты используешь, и посмотри - выводит тебе 1 запись или две.

Comment: не понял....навикат, пхпадин

Comment: Ну как ты в базу заливаешь данные, просматриваешь их в базе?

Comment: mysql. select сверху пример!

Comment: Загугли navicat for mysql